# CKEditor 5 custom build toolbar not showing

Tags: ckeditor5

I have been messing with this for days now but everytime I start trying to add a simpleuploadadapter to the code here the toolbar disappears i.e. remove the line plugins: [ SimpleUploadAdapter, ... ], and all is fine.

I am new to CKEDitor and do find the documentation a bit lacking for a new user

Here is my code
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
plugins: [ SimpleUploadAdapter, ... ], // remove this line and the toolbar appears!

```
                     toolbar: {
          
                items: [
                    'heading',
                    '|',
                    'bold',
                    'italic',
                    'link',
                    'underline',
                    'horizontalLine',
                    'fontBackgroundColor',
                    'fontColor',
                    'fontFamily',
                    'alignment',
                    'bulletedList',
                    'numberedList',
                    '|',
                    'indent',
                    'outdent',
                    '|',
                    'imageUpload',
                    'blockQuote',
                    'insertTable',
                    'mediaEmbed',
                    'undo',
                    'redo',
                    'highlight',
                    'specialCharacters']
                    },language: 'en',image: {toolbar: ['imageTextAlternative','imageStyle:full','imageStyle:side']},
            table: {
                contentToolbar: [
                    'tableColumn',
                    'tableRow',
                    'mergeTableCells',
                    'tableCellProperties'
                ]
            },
            licenseKey: '',
            
        } )
        .then( editor => {
            window.editor = editor;
                  } )
                  
           
                  
                  
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( 'Oops, something went wrong!' );
            console.error( 'Please, report the following error on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues with the build id and the error stack trace:' );
            console.warn( 'Build id: 2s2liiisdwtn-fs46wvie39gh' );
            console.error( error );
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your installation custom built or not? If not, did you try to create a custom built setup including that plugin then try checking by loading its sample file? It would help us to see by eliminating the possibilities that anything else on your page design might interfere. Could you please be more clear?

Regards...

Comment: Sorry for tacking so long to reply, yes it is a custom build using the online custom build tool. and followed the documentation for installing and running the build

Comment: OK I have now used base64uploadadapter instead of the simpleuploadadapter and now have it working, I would still however like to know what I need to do to get the latter to work as have read everything and tried others examples all without success